# Closest element to a subset of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $U=\{(x,y)|x,y\geq 0\}$ be a closed convex subspace of $(\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty )$.

Show that the closest elements in $U$ to $(1,-1)$ are $\{(x,0)|0\leq x\leq 2\}$

Show that the closest elements in $U$ to $(0,-1)$ are $\{(x,0)|0\leq x\leq 1\}$

I have noticed the question is for multi points and not a single point. However as far as i understand the closest element (in single) to $(1,-1)$ is $(1,0)$. Am I missing something? Also what do I need the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest element in $U$ to $(1,-1)$ is $(1,0)$ in the *Euclidean* metric, but in the metric $||\cdot ||_\infty$, all points in the set $\{(x,0) \mid 0 \leq x \leq 2\}$ are equally close to $(1,-1)$.

Recall that $||(x,y)-(x',y')||_\infty = \max\{|x-x'|,|y-y'|\}$. Can you use this definition to show

(a) all elements in $\{(x,0)\mid 0 \leq x \leq 2\}$ are equally close to $(1,-1)$ (you should be able to compute $||(x,0)-(1,-1)||_\infty$ explicitly for $0 \leq x \leq 2$), and

(b) all other elements of $U$ are strictly further from $(1,-1)$?

Similarly for the second part of the problem.